# Ruby on Rails on Google Cloud Engine

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a Ruby stack on GCE with Passenger. It was the default click-to-deploy option.

Now to serve my app I placed it in /var/www/app-name/

I edited the virtual host file for the same with this

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app-name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app-name/public
    <Directory /var/www/app-name/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

I have edited the host file too to include the IP of the project

Apache still can't serve the Rails app. What am i doing wrong? I am new at cloud hosting and Rails and there is no proper documentation for this to follow.

Any kind of help appreciated :)

Comment: What error do you get?  The more detail you can provide the better.  Also, please update your tags to include your the Rails version you are using as that may impact the solution.

Comment: I dont get anything. The default apache page of "It works" shows.

Comment: @steveklein Do you think i need to take another step in installing passenger?

Comment: Sorry @Hetu I am not very familiar with Apache/Passenger.  I deploy my apps with NGINX/Unicorn.  I've had a lot of success with the Digital Ocean tutorials so maybe one of them could help.  One last Q - is `app-name` on your `ServerName` directive the domain you are looking to resolve?  I think it needs to be something like `www.example.com` (not `example`) - probably an obvious point but just checking.